# scrollview is not scrolling completly

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

In my main activity there is navigation drawer and fab button and inside content.xml which is the main xml to load content in my Main activity. In other word, I've navigation drawer activity provided by android studio.

Code in that content.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#f0eb79"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/computer"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="Chemistry"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#2f2e2e"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#524d47"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/computer"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="Sports"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#e7595d"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/computer"
                android:paddingLeft="45dp"
                android:text="Inventions"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And it is not completely scrolling as shown in the figure below. I also tested same xml code into another empty activity where there is NOT fab and nagivation drawer and there it is showing scrolling behaviour perfectly.

[image]

Similarly, this is my activitymain.xml's code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your activity_main.xml by editing your post. content.xml seems okay.

Comment: @KMRejowanAhmmed sir I've just added it, please check and help me.

Comment: can you public @layout/nav_header_main and @menu/activity_main_drawer? I tested and It's scrolling

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after adding these attribute in scrollview:

```xml
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
tools:context="com.example.nepali_test.MainActivity" 
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
```